# Sentiment analysis in realtime feed using NTLk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, praw

I would like to know if its feasible analyse headlines news  (using NTLK /sentiment vader) in realtime/streaming news.

Below the code that feed my system of news (headlines)

```
import praw
import time


reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxx',
client_secret='MLK5gKaEM2FxxxxxxxxI', user_agent='testing_api')



  # must be edited to properly authenticate
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('worldnews')
seen_submissions = set()

while True:
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10):
        if submission.fullname not in seen_submissions:
            seen_submissions.add(submission.fullname)
            print('{} {}\n'.format(submission.title, submission.url))
    time.sleep(60)  # sleep for a minute (60 seconds)
```

Using  **SentimentIntensityAnalyzer**  I built:

```
from IPython import display
import math
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style='darkgrid', context='talk', palette='Dark2')

import praw 

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxx',
client_secret='MLK5gKaEM2FxxxxxxxxI', user_agent='testing_api')
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('worldnews')


headlines = set()

while True:
  for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10):
   if submission.title not in headlines:
       headlines.add(submission.title)
time.sleep(60)  # sleep for a minute (60 seconds)







from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as SIA

sia = SIA()
results = []


for line in headlines:
    pol_score = sia.polarity_scores(line)
    pol_score['headline'] = line
    results.append(pol_score)

pprint(results[], width=100)
```

I can´t see anything displayed in the console... I'm expecting to see something like (in realtime)

```
 {'compound': -0.5267,
  'headline': 'Report: Nearly Half of Americans Breathing Unhealthy Air',
  'neg': 0.327,
  'neu': 0.673,
  'pos': 0.0},
 {'compound': -0.0754,
  'headline': 'The Implications of Trump Derangement Syndrome | Even now, vehement Trump '
              'supporters seem to believe that most criticism of the president is explained by '
              'widespread TDS.',
  'neg': 0.11,
  'neu': 0.791,
  'pos': 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you included a complete example.  You still need to call `polarity_scores()` and add it to your data structure.

For example, if you were to use a dictionary:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit( ... )
sub = reddit.subreddit('worldnews')
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

results = {}
posts = sub.new(limit=10)
for post in posts:
    title = post.title
    if title in results:
        # skip title if previously encountered
        continue

    score = analyzer.polarity_scores(title)
    results[title] = score
    results[title]['headline'] = title
```

You could also make the query and loop more efficient by searching by date or just keeping track of the timestamp on the last post seen and short circuiting a loop for the other posts and use the original `set()` like you started with.

```
results = set()

...

    if post.created > last_date:
        break

    last_date = post.created
    score = analyzer.polarity_scores(post.title)
    score['headline'] = post.title
    results.add(score)
```

You might find this tutorial helpful to get more detail about building a system like that:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5269358/Introducing-NLTK-for-Natural-Language-Processing-w